# The type or namespace CodeAnalysis does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac

Tags: c#, sql-server-data-tools

Attempting to create the example in the walkthrough: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632175(v=vs.103).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632175%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) I am using VS2013.

In the section 'Defining the LocalizedExportCodeAnalysisRuleAttribute Class' I am getting the following error:

The type or namespace CodeAnalysis does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac

Comment: `Microsfot` - really? (you have it twice)

Comment: Typo when I wrote the post. it's correct in the code.

Comment: have you installed vis studio 2013 on a machine which previously had vis studio 2012 perchance? If so, you may need to reinstall SSDT.

Comment: @brumScouse I did. Thanks, I will attempt that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac library is part of the SQL Server SDK and not necessarily "default" library that comes with Visual Studio.

You can download the SDK through the SQL Server Data Tools library [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx). After installing, it should have the libraries you need. You'll then want to make sure you add a reference to the library in your project before continuing.

Comment: I was able to add the reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac to my project. However, the only namespaces available are data, deployment, extensibility, extensions, and model.

Comment: Have you tried adding Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.CodeAnalysis? Sometimes you need to add the full library.

Answer (score 0):

the code analysis namespace is under Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions and not Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac